# how to get network system DateTime using ip of that system

Tags: c#, datetime, network-programming

I have a windows application on network that can be executed at multiple locations in that network but the problem is, it's dependent on date and time.

Is there any possibility that I get DateTime from server using IP or any other way?
So I can maintain same date and time.

Comment: This is normally done by making one of the machines an NTP server. All the other machines update their date/time from it periodically. And the NTP server of course updates its date/time from an upstream NTP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement following>>

```
public static DateTime GetNistTime()
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://....");
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";
    req.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore); //No caching
    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        StreamReader st = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
        string html = st.ReadToEnd().ToUpper();
        string time = Regex.Match(html, @">\d+:\d+:\d+<").Value; //HH:mm:ss format
        string date = Regex.Match(html, @">\w+,\s\w+\s\d+,\s\d+<").Value; //dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
        dt= DateTime.Parse((date + " " + time).Replace(">", "").Replace("<", ""));
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how a simple HTTP Get request will get the server time? I believe you will have to implement NTP (Network Time Protocol) to fetch the server time.